# Generally what is put in the main method and what isn't? - java

Tags: java

Beginner just starting out

.can i write entirety of code outside of main and still run? generally i'm asking what is "main" used for?

Comment: [Entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java)

Comment: Main is the entry point of your application.  It's the method that's run when you run your program. You could write your application logic elsewhere but you have to run it from main method.

Comment: You should read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can just code everything in main and in will work. However to make your code structured you probably want to code outside of main and call it from main.

Answer (score 0):

The main Method is the start point for the VM of Java. So if you want to run your application, there has to be a main method. Not only Java has this concept, also other OOP-Programminglanguages like C,C++,C#. You can write code outside the main. but remember that the code can only be accessed if there is a way to it from the main Method, example functions.

Answer (score 0):

The main method is where your system is able to call and start the program up. The main method is needed if you wish to run your program and make use of your other classes.

You can create your program inside the main method if you wish, but as your programs become more sophisticated, you are going to want to create other classes that are initialized and used in your main method.

For example, if you make two classes called "Suv" "Sedan", and make one more class called "Mechanic" - the class that will hold your main - you can initialize Suv and Sedan and you can call the methods you made in Suv and Sedan to do things like change the engine, or to change the color, etc.

If you are just learning java, then don't worry about it too much and just write your code in your main method.

Answer (score 0):

Main is the entry point of any java application. The Java Virtual Machine starts up by loading a specified class and then invoking the method `main` in this specified class.

You can write your code in main method, or somewhere else and call that in the main method in the order in which you want to execute it.

The method main must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. Following is the reason for it:

- `public`:- `main` is marked public so that it can be accessed from anywhere outside the scope of the class or broadly we can say outside the scope of project.
- `static`:- It is marked static so that it can be called without any instance of the class. Without declaring main method static, your program will compile successfully but throw an error at run time.
- `void`:- The keyword void is used with `main` to tell the JVM that the main method does not return any value. It is solely for the initiation of the application not for returning anything.

Following is the valid declaration of the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

public static void main(String... args)
```